# How can I get XSLT to return UTF-8 in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to get my XSL script to work with UTF-8 encoding. Characters like åäö and greek characters just turn up like garbage. The only way to get it to work is if I write the result to a file. If I write it to an output stream it only returns garbage (System.out works, but that might be because its beeing redirected to a file).

The result needs to be returned from a servlet, and please note that its not a servlet configuration issue. I can return a hard coded string with greek characters from the servlet and it works fine, so it's an issue with the transformation.

Here is my current (simplified) code.

```
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
IOException {
    try {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        final TransformerFactory factory = this.getFactory();

        final File inFile = new File("infile.xml");
        final File xslFile = new File("template.xsl");
        final File outFile = new File("outfile.html");

        final Templates templates = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(xslFile));
        final Transformer transformer = templates.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        final StreamSource source = new StreamSource(in);

        final StreamResult result1 = new StreamResult(outFile);
        final StreamResult result2 = new StreamResult(System.out);
        final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final StreamResult result3 = new StreamResult(out);

        //transformer.transform(source, result1);
        //transformer.transform(source, result2);
        transformer.transform(source, result3);

        final Writer writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write(new String(out.toByteArray()));
        writer.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (final TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, my XSL script contains the following

```
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
```

What is the correct way to get this to work? I'm using Saxon for the transformation if that might be of any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is almost certainly the problem:

```
writer.write(new String(out.toByteArray()));
```

You've carefully encoded your text as UTF-8, and then you're converting into a string *using the platform default encoding*. You should pretty much *never* use the `String` constructors and methods which use the platform default encoding. Even if you *want* to use that encoding, do so explicitly.

If you're going to write to a `Writer` anyway, why are you starting off writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Why not go straight to the `Writer`?

It would be better, however, to write straight to the response's output stream (`response.getOutputStream()`), and also set the response's content type to indicate that it's UTF-8.

Note that if you really want to get the result as a `String` beforehand, use `StringWriter`. There's no point in writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then converting to a string.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me into the right direction. I just found that the `ByteArrayOutputStream` had the method `out.toString("UTF-8")` so it worked after that. I cannot use the response stream right away since I have some other stuff to do with the result as well, but I think I can get this going now. Thanks!

Comment: I was about to answer this question and then I see @jonSkeet 0_0

Comment: If you want the output as a string of characters to be processed by a Java app, just get the transformer to output characters, by supplying a Writer. Asking it to write bytes to a byteOutputStream, and then decoding the bytes as characters, just creates complexity and potential for error.